# How can i read a .txt file in datatable in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable, readfile

im new to rails and i want to read a .txt file and save it into a database that looks like this:

```
ThomasLinde2 ; PeterParker2;Montagmorgen;        1.00
JulkoAndrovic3 ; KeludowigFrau1;Montagmorgen;        1.00
JohannesWoellenstein4 ; SiegmundoKrugmando3;Montagmittag;        1.00
LenaLobenswert8 ; KlausGause4;Montagmittag;        1.00
```

Now i want to read this .txt file to my datatable. My Code for this look like this:

```
  def read_optimization_results

if (File.exist?("Zuordnung_x.txt"))

fi=File.open("Zuordnung_x.txt", "r")
fi.each { |line|
  sa=line.split(";")
  sa0=sa[0].delete "\n"
  sa1=sa[1].delete "\n"
  sa2=sa[2].delete "\n"

  solution = Solution.find_by_period(sa2)
  solution.request = sa0
  solution.offer = sa1
  solution.period = sa2
  solution.save
}
fi.close
else
  flash.now[:not_available] = "Die Lösung wurde noch nicht berechnet!"
end
@solutions = Solution.all
render :template => "solutions/index"

end
```

The relevant Datatable consist of:

```
  create_table "solutions", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "request"
t.string   "offer"
t.string   "period"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

If i do `read_optimization_results` i always get the `no method error: undefined method 'reqeust'`any ideas?

Comment: What's the question here? Does you code work? Do you ask for a cleaner solution here or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: sorry look edited question

Comment: Can't reproduce. Post a [mcve].

Comment: `reqeust` -  you have a mistype somewhere in your code

Comment: But it's not in the code shown here. Have a look in your log file and read the back trace of the error.

Comment: hm i checked this and i think there is no mistake. Something to to with `solution_find_by(...)` ? I think like something in the answer below. It must be unique or something. I dont understand the syntax of this code

Comment: @Feidex can you show the backtrace of the error?

Comment: i am very new to rails so i dont really know what backtrace ist. Do you mean this: 
Local Variables

line 
"ThomasLinde2 ; PeterParker2;Montagmorgen; 1.00\n"
sa 
["ThomasLinde2 ", " PeterParker2", "Montagmorgen", " 1.00\n"]
sa0 
"ThomasLinde2 "
sa1 
" PeterParker2"
sa2 
"Montagmorgen"
splitforid 
["Montagmorgen"]
solution 
nil
fi 
#<File:Zuordnung_x.txt>

Comment: i got the solution the answer of AMShargar helped

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) here. What you basically have are values seperated by semicolon.

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  # use row here...
end
```

Instead of `value.delete "\n"` I'd suggest using `value.strip`([docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-strip)) to remove whitespaces and line breaks around your value.

Regarding `Solution`, you are lacking a unique identifier. If you do `Solution.find_by_period(...)` you can always only have one instance with that `period` and it mut exist beforehand.

I'd imagine you'd like to create a new `Solution`. This would be done with `Solution.create! request: column[0], offer: column[1], period: column[2]`

Comment: i think the error happens because of the lacking unique identifier. From where i need this identifier? something written in the .txt file ? like

ThomasLinde2- ; PeterParker2;Montagmorgen;        1.00

JulkoAndrovic3- ; KeludowigFrau1;Montagmorgen;        1.00


every "sa0" contains a "-". Is this the ways i can identify?